# Python Enum with default for undefined value

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy

I realize Enum's are for restricting possible values, but for my case, I'm using them with a third-party API that will add strings that I convert to SQLAlchemy enums (which are just enum.Enums) in the future without warning.

I don't want to get KeyErrors when these new values come in, so I'd like to log a warning and assign a default of

SomeEnum.Undefined

to each and every Enum I define. Problem is enums.Enum can't be subclassed.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want with EnumMeta, or am I thinking about the problem wrong?

Comment: `enum.Enum` can be sub-classed: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html. Try overriding `__getattribute__`.

Comment: You probably have a work-around by now, but I would still like to answer this question -- are you saying that you want a parent `Enum` with an `Undefined` member that your other `Enum`s can inherit from?